# Working on remote dekstop VBA

Tags: vba, excel, automation, remote-access

I just started working in BI Reporting and I have a project I hope you will help me.

I would like to do few simple things on remote desktop:

1. Start the connection and log in - DONE (all other steps are on remote desktop through mstsc connection)
2. Click "OK" button on the screen (information security note, which pops up every time - before desktop shows itself)
3. Wait about 1 minute (I think I now how to do this)
4. Start program - it has shortcut on desktop (it's bat file that does things on the database)

I've tried over and over again but have no luck. Hope that you will be able to help me, guide or provide a good example. I am quite new to VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an automation software like uipath, automation anywhere, network automation, etc.
Haven't try the others but for sure UiPath can do the job of automating remote desktops. Here are [some demos.](http://pages.uipath.com/tutorials/citrix-automation-data-entry)